# How can I get notifications from Google when they deprecate an API?

Tags: php, api, safe-browsing

Recently, our whole site was stymied because we used Google safe browsing api code that they recently deprecated. If we had know, we would have moved to the newest API.  This isn't the only Google api that changed on us, without us knowing. How can we get notifications from Google that they're about to deprecate an api?